# Repeat the test suite for different input parameters in Test::Unit ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, testunit

We are building a QA automation setup with test::unit and selenium. Tests for each page in our web app lives in separate directory, and at the top level directory, we have this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'test/unit/runner/html'
require 'test/unit/ui/html/html_runner.rb'

Dir["*/test_*.rb"].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

This creates a dynamic test suite and executes it. Inside the test scripts, there is a configuration file, which has configurations for the selenium browser driver to be used, the base url to start with, etc. We have to run the tests with all the browsers. Currently, we have to manually edit the configuration and change the selenium driver name from say, 'chrome' to 'firefox' each time after the suite is executed, and manually run it again. Can we instead set at the top level script so that the whole test suite repeats some 'x' number of times for different configurations?

Comment: What is your setup like?  You run all your tests on a single box?  Are you using any CI tool like Jenkins?

Comment: Yes we have just setup hudson for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Hudson, you could go with wonky Selenium Server approach where for each job (running the tests under a given browser), you can start up Selenium Server with forcedBrowserMode set to whatever browser you want to test under.